# Suggestions for caching a dataset

Tags: delphi, caching, devart

I'd like to perform the following:

1) Open a dataset (using TMSQuery, SDAC DevArt component)

2) caching the content to disk (imagine a list of cutsomers)

3) the next time I need to Open the dataset I will first populate it with cached data, then I will just Refresh it by calling TMSQuery.RefreshQuick  method.

In this way I plan to obtain a substantial improvement in speed, because I don't need to retrieve records that I already retrieved in previous application runs.

How can I obtain this caching? I have many datamodules with TMSQuery, so somehow I would like to have a global routine that checks that everytime I try to Open a TMSQuery, if that query is somehow tagged i will try to restore from cache, call RefreshQuick, in case this fails I will call Open.

Can you please suggest?

(I use Delphi 2009 and SDAC 4.80)

Comment: When refreshing your data, you have to compare it to the values in the database, so you still have to query all data. How does this improve speed? You have a DateModified field or something?

Comment: I plan to use TMSQuery.RegreshQuick method.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [`TClientDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBClient.TClientDataSet) and [`TDataSetProvider`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Provider.TDataSetProvider) components for this, connecting the components in this way.

TMSQuery->TDataSetProvider->TClientDataSet

The [`TClientDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBClient.TClientDataSet) is a very good alternative to persist and retrieve data from an disk.

see these links for more info about the ClientDataset

- [Using the MIDAS ClientDataset as a replacement for cached updates](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/22571)
- [A Guide to Using the TClientDataSet in Delphi Database Applications](http://delphi.about.com/b/2008/03/03/a-guide-to-using-the-tclientdataset-in-delphi-applications.htm)
- [Effective ClientDataSets and the BriefCase Model](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin64.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 things:

1. Make descendant of the TMSQuery component and override the Open function
   (you search all you datamodule .dfm and .pas files with TMSQuery and replace with TCachedTMSQuery)
2. Detour/hook the TMSQuery.Open (runtime patching)